# Property [apps] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get apps from each categories but its giving me **Property [apps] does not exist on this collection instance**

Here's the blade

```
@foreach($app_categories->apps as $item)  @endforeach
```

Controller

```
$app_categories = AppCategory::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

Category model

```
public function apps()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App::class, 'app_categories_relate')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

App Model

```
public function appcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(AppCategory::class, 'app_categories_relate');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
@foreach($app_categories->apps as $item)  @endforeach
```

`$app_categories` is a `Collection`, so you can't access `apps`. You need to iterate twice:

```
@foreach($app_categories as $app_category)
  @foreach($app_category->apps as $item)
    ...
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Or, return a single `AppCategory`:

```
$app_category = AppCategory::orderBy('name', 'asc')->first();

...

@foreach($app_category->apps as $item)
  ...
@endforeach
```

Edit: The other answers suggesting to use `with()` are useful for improving performance, but **is not required for this to work.** If you don't use `->with('apps')`, performance will suffer due to `N+1` query logic (executing multiple queries in a loop as opposed to pre-loading them)

Answer (score 0):

you have to eager load the relation first in the controller as:

```
$app_categories = AppCategory::with('apps')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```